# Направление пистолета в сторону виртуального джойстика (аналог)

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я скачал готовый ассет, на моей 2.5 д игре персонаж (точнее оружие) должен прицеливаться (смотреть) в сторону, куда направлен аналоговый виртуальный стик. Но он поворачивается по оси Y, я не очень разбираюсь, помогите. Вот код примерно:

```
public Transform Gun; // объект для вращения по оси Z
public Joystick joy;
    void Update()
{
    Vector3 moveVector = (Vector3.right * joy.Horizontal + Vector3.forward * joy.Vertical);
    Gun.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveVector);
}

moveVector как правильнее сделать?
```

Вот код самого джойстика (плавающий, появляется там, где нажал)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class FloatingJoystick : Joystick
{
Vector2 joystickCenter = Vector2.zero;

void Start()
{
    background.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

public override void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Vector2 direction = eventData.position - joystickCenter;
    inputVector = (direction.magnitude > background.sizeDelta.x / 2f) ? direction.normalized : direction / (background.sizeDelta.x / 2f);
    ClampJoystick();
    handle.anchoredPosition = (inputVector * background.sizeDelta.x / 2f) * handleLimit;
}

public override void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    background.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    background.position = eventData.position;
    handle.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
    joystickCenter = eventData.position;
}

public override void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    background.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    inputVector = Vector2.zero;
}
```

}

Comment: stop, стрелять вперед это X ось должно быть или Z? X же,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых кидай писать 2.5д. Это 2д и НЕ ВАЖНО как выглядят спрайты. Это или 3д или 2д. Не существует 2,5мерного мира.

Во-вторых ты вращаешь обьект в плоскости. Представь Х - горизонтальной линией. Y - вертикальной линией. Z - это точка. То есть линия вглубину.

Тебе нужно вращение в плоскости XY. То есть вокруг точки Z. Заходишь в юнити, создаешь тэстовую сцену с канвасом и кидаешь туда спрайт. Выбираешь инструмент вращения и проверяешь. правильно ли я все написал. Авось я обманул и нужно в другой плоскости поворачивать.

Теперь представим себе аналоговый виртуальный джостик. Он направлен  в какую-то сторону. Ты берешь градус отклонения джостика и присваиваешь твоему спрайту.

Если у него нету вывода в градусах, тебе нужно вычислить этот градус. Для этого скорее всего нужно будет вспомнить геометрию/тригонометрию....

Это максимум что я могу подсказать ибо я не знаю что за джостик ты юзал и каковы у него есть данные на выходе.

Но общая идея именно такая.

---

И еще:

- переменная у тебя должна называтся rotation а не moveVector. Ты поворачиваешь оружие, а не двигаешь его в плоскости.
- твой следующий вопрос будет о pivot Point. Гуглить по словам "unity pivot point change"

Comment: насчет названия, да, поменяю, это просто был скрипт передвижения объекта тем самым стиком. Добавил код джойстика выше в вопросе

Comment: А всё, сделал, так: Vector3 moveVector = (Vector3.up * joy.Horizontal + Vector3.left * joy.Vertical); Gun.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, moveVector);